# Can two electromagnets with the same power source have a force on each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electronics

In theory, it seems like an obvious yes, so I tried setting up two coils connected in series with opposing B fields. Maybe there's something wrong with my setup, or I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Not only can two coils exert force on each other, but each turn of the wire in a single coil force on its neighbors.

Comment: What's the power source? Is it DC? Can you include a circuit diagram of your setup? Do you have a multimeter that you can use to check voltages around the circuit? FWIW, there are sites you can use to create circuit diagrams, eg https://www.circuit-diagram.org/

Comment: I cant create a diagram since im on my phone, but I just wrapped a coil with 30 turns around a screwdriver and then wrapped it the opposit way 30 more times then taped them to keep them from unravelling. I put 1.5 volts through it, and theres no observable force, but there is a change in current when I move them.

Comment: Instead of wrapping all the turns around the same screwdriver, try wrapping half of them around one, and half around another.